# Manipulating a variable containing XML with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I'm using AJAX to receive an XML response, which I then need to manipulate. By using jQuery's context option, I can select from the XML data, but I am still unable to write to it.

```
$('blah', xml)
```

selects xml just fine, but

```
$('blah', xml).removeClass( 'myClass' )
```

seems to do nothing to the xml variable! How can I achieve the functionality I'm looking for?

Example:

```
var data = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
   type:"GET",
   url:"blah/blah.jsp",
   success:function(msg)
   {
      data = msg;
      init();
   }
});

function init()
{
   $('#myElement', data).removeClass('hidden');//removeAttr('class') also fails
}
```

Example xml file:

```
<root>
<div>
<!--lots of content -->
</div>
<div>
<p id = "myElement<->" class = "hidden">
  Test!
</p>
</div>
</root>
```

Comment: May we see the XML file?

Comment: addClass/removeClass are HTML specific, they modify the attribute named class.  Can you tell us if removeAttr works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test Page</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
    var data = null;
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"sample.xml",
        dataType: 'xml',
        success:function(msg)
        {
           init( $(msg) );
        }
    });

    function init( $xml )
    {
      var $myElement = $xml.find( '#myElement' );
      $myElement.removeAttr( 'class' );
      console.log( $myElement );
    }
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<div>

</div>
<div>
<p id = "myElement" class = "hidden">
  Test!
</p>
</div>
</root>
```

so make sure you are requesting with `"xml"` as the `dataType` option, and that your JSP page returns the content with the correct Content-Type header (text/xml)

Comment: *repeatedly clicks up vote, hoping it might shoot to 100.*

Content-type on a jsp response header. What a subtle bug.

Comment: Also be aware of the possibility of needing to use msg.d instead of just msg. http://encosia.com/2009/02/10/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/